# Django - call Model save() without using "objects" Manager get_queryset

Tags: django, django-models

I'm developing a legacy Django 1.7 system for a client.  The programmers before me overrode the Member model (basically the User model) "objects" property with a filter query that removes anything with "is_deleted" set to "True".  I've listed the snippets below:

Member class snippet:

```
class Member(AbstractUser):
    objects = MemberManager()
    all_objects = models.Manager()
```

MemberManager class snippet:

```
class MemberManager(BaseUserManager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(MemberManager, self).get_queryset().filter(is_deleted=False)
```

Now when I try to update a user that has the is_deleted flag set to "True" it fails.  Below is an example code snippet.  Notice how I use "all_objects" which is the default models.Manager() that returns all records.

```
user = Member.all_objects.get(pk=id) # id of an is_deleted = True record
user.is_deleted = False
user.save()
```

This code causes this Django query to run which unfortunately has "is_deleted = 0" included in the WHERE clause, which causes it to not find the record.  Below is what shows up in the logs:

> UPDATE `Member` [[snip...]] WHERE (`Member`.`is_deleted` = 0 AND `Member`.`id` = 6)

Is there any way to call "save()" that will not use the MemberManager.objects get_queryset filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried Kevin Christopher Henry's answer and unfortunately changing the default manager messed up the authentication code, which needed to inherit from the "BaseUserManager" class.  The solution was to create an "undelete" function in the Member model class that uses the "all_objects" property to undelete the user before it's saved.

```
class Member(AbstractUser):
    objects = MemberManager() # default manager
    all_objects = models.Manager()

    def undelete(self):
        if self.is_deleted:
            Member.all_objects.filter(id=self.id).update(is_deleted=False)
```

Then in my code I did this:

```
user = Member.all_objects.get(pk=id)
user.undelete()
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem stems from having `MemberManager` listed first. As [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/managers/#default-managers) says:

> Take note that the first `Manager` Django encounters (in the order in which they’re defined in the model) has a special status. Django interprets the first `Manager` defined in a class as the "default" `Manager`, and several parts of Django will use that `Manager` exclusively for that model. As a result, it’s a good idea to be careful in your choice of default manager in order to avoid a situation where overriding `get_queryset()` results in an inability to retrieve objects you’d like to work with.

Reversing the order of `objects` and `all_objects` should fix the problem.